# warning LNK4006: "unsigned char * XXX" (?XXX@@3PAEA) already defined in WWWWW.o; second definition ignored

Tags: c++, visual-c++, linker

I am declaring and defining a font data in font.h file like this:

```
#ifndef _DEFAULT_FONT_H
#define _DEFAULT_FONT_H

const unsigned char wwDefaultFont_TextureData[] = 
{
    0x00,0x01,0x00,0x00,0x40,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x20,0x00,0x00,0x00,
};

#endif
```

and I am planing to use this array in render.h file. 
So I am including it as #include "font.h"

```
#include "font.h"

class render{

};
```

But I am getting link warning LNK4006 error?

What would be the best way to declare this variable and avoid this linking warning?

Comment: Look up what `extern` does.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie `const unsigned char x[] = { 'a' , 'b' };` would be correct; `const` variables have internal linkage

Comment: post a minimal but complete example that illustrates the problem. include the compiler version, build command and exact error message.

Comment: you can't get that error when you only have one file including this...

Comment: Well I am getting this warning nevertheless! 

I fixed this warning by adding a font.cpp. I declare the variable as extern in font.h and defined the variable in font.cpp. Then I included the header file in my render.h.

Answer (score -1):

I think you may not define a header file macro to avoid the header file included repeatedly.
If that's true, you have two ways to avoid this:

1. Use

   ```
   #ifndef _FONT_H_
   #define _FONT_H_
   //font.h content
   ...
   #endif
   ```

   to make sure it included for only once
2. If you only use the const variant in font.h,you can use extern to claim it and you need not to include the header file